# Unable to write to a text file in Java

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I have this code inside of a ButtonListener class. I'm not really sure what the issue is because this worked when I ran it in a separate tester program. The JOptionPane shows up when I hit the fileButton in my GUI and takes in a user input, but it never writes a text file.

```
        if (source == fileButton)
        {
            String info = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("File name?");
            info += ".txt";

            try
            {
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(info);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

                pw.println("test");
                pw.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: Try closing `fw` instead of/as well as `pw` to make sure all the resources are closed and flushed

Comment: Also consider using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) instead

Comment: First, change your System.err.println to `e.printStrackTrace();`.  Exceptions are very valuable for determining what went wrong and why.  Second, are you sure the current directory is the same each time you run the program?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).